# Where is Cadillac CTS 2007 3.6 OBD2 connector?

Tags: computer, cadillac

I changed my pertol cap since old one wore down to the point where I am unsure it will open in petrol station. The one that I got shuts tank ok, but sensor is indicating that cap is open - which in turn switches engine light on dash, and then I have to go to local garage pay £30 to reset the codes (I could ignore the light but then if real fault occurs I will not know about it and it might cause damage by continuing to drive).
After few journeys like that and them even doing if for free (I guess felling awkward to charge for same thing every couple of weeks). I figured I will get myself OBD2 connector and start reseting them myself. I got myself a cable but cant find where to plug it it.

**Where is ODB2 connector located?**

Comment: I don't know, but I had another GM vehicle where the connector was under the plastic panel by the gear lever. In most cars, they're underneath the steering wheel somewhere.

Comment: My '99 Jetta's ODB connector was under the radio and next to the ashtray in the center of the dash behind a little plastic panel, so it's _probably_ under the steering wheel somewhere, but it doesn't have to be!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be under the dash just to the right of the hood release (based on some internet searching).

**EDIT:** The connector itself should look like this:

[image]

Most GM vehicles have it just beyond the dash plastic underneath. Since this is a Caddie, it may be under a panel. [This video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=oROk0G9i3QM) may be of a little help to you.

Comment: Could you please add link to this video to your answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oROk0G9i3QM current one is pretty useless. Thanks.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius, No problem - someone edited my original post to add that video.  I didn't like it much either, but then again, I only clicked on it after you mentioned it.